# Get a subString from a String

Tags: java, android

I have the below string. I need to get the date as a separate string.

```
String string = "Total payment is INR 7,000. Please pay a minimum amount of INR 320 by 03-JUL-15 to avoid charges."
```

Expected result: `"03-JUL-15"`

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to format the string in source code (either backticks or as a separate line indented 4+ spaces), so that we can tell exactly where your string begins and ends.

Comment: Is the format of your string always going to be same ??

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What is your question? You've just listed a requirement and shown no effort. Please show your code so far and explain the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String string = "Total payment is INR 7,000. Please pay a minimum amount of INR 320 by 03-JUL-15 to avoid charges."

String date = string.subString(string.lastIndexOf("by") + 3, string.lastIndexOf("to") - 1);
```

**Explanation: string.subString(int start, int end);**

This returns a string containing the given subsequence of this string which will result in the date you want.

Comment: Well, now you've just copied devlopp's solution. Additionally, your edit to the question is totally invalid. You modified their input string. Corrections to grammar/spelling is good, but DON'T modify stuff like that. It might literally be the string they are working with and you may have even invalidated answers by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

if "by" is always the last channel before the date and TT is the chain following the date.

```
String result = chaine.substring(chaine.lastIndexOf("by")+3, chaine.lastIndexOf("to")-1)
```

Comment: This does not work. This gives you the desired string and everything after it.

Comment: Looks like that should work. I removed my downvote but I won't upvote either... see my comment on the other answer by Hussein.

Comment: yes, i know it's work, but i think it's one solution

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use REGEX to get the substring. You create a Pattern of the value you want. In your case, it will be something like:

```
String string = "Total payment is INR 7,000. Please pay a minimum amount of INR 320 by 03-JUL-15 to avoid charges.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}\\p{Punct}[A-Z]{3}\\p{Punct}\\d{2}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    // Found your string.

}
```

You can check the reference below to see the definition of each character in the pattern.

```
\p{Punct}   Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
\d          A digit: [0-9]
[A-Z]       Chars from A to Z uppercase
{n}         Repeat 'n' times that pattern
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).